# ./test: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to create new instance by taking inputs from user

source /root/keystonerc_admin
unset http_proxy

function main {
    echo "Please choose:
    1. Create instance from an image
    2. Create instance from a volume
    3. Exit"

    While true do
        read SELECT
        case "$SELECT" in
            1) SELECT=func_create_from_image;;
            2) SELECT=func_create_from_volume;;
            3) SELECT=exit;;
            *) echo Invalid selection.; continue
        esac
        break
    done
}

function func_create_from_image {
echo "List of flavors"
nova flavor-list
echo "Enter flavor id from the list"
read flavor_id

echo "List of images"
nova image-list
echo "Enter image id from the list"
read image_id

echo "List of security groups"
nova secgroup-list --all-tenants
echo "Enter security group name from the list"
read secgroup_name

echo "List of keypairs"
nova keypair-list
echo "Enter keypair name from the list"
read keypair_id

echo "Enter display name of instance"
read display_name

## use "set" for debugging
##set -x
nova boot --display $display_name --flavor $flavor_id --image $image_id \
--key_name $keypair_id --security_group $secgroup_name
##set +x
}

function func_create_from_volume {
echo "Please choose:
1. Use existing bootable volume
2. Create new bootable volume 
3. Exit"

while true do
    read SELECT
    case "$SELECT" in
        1) SELECT=create_instance_from__existing_volume;;

        2) SELECT=create_instance_from_new_volume;;

        3) SELECT=exit;;

        *) echo Invalid selection.; continue

        esac
        break

    done
}

create_instance_from_new_volume {

        echo "Specify image id from the below list"
        nova image-list
        read image_id

        echo "specify size in GB, only specify number"
        read vol_size

        echo "Specify image name to be displayed in cinder list"
        read vol_disp_name

        set -x
        cinder create --image-id $image_id --display-name $vol_disp_name $vol_size
        set +x

        echo "volume created"
        cinder list

        echo "create instance"
        create_instance_from__existing_volume
}

create_instance_from_existing_volume {

        echo "Specify volume id from the below list"
        cinder list
        read vol_id

            echo "Pick flavor id from the below list"
        nova flavor-list
        read flavor_id

        echo "specify size in GB, only specify number or leave blank for system to decide"
        read vol_size

        echo "Specify type of volume either snap or other or leave blank if not known"
        read vol_type

        echo "Specify 1 if volume should be deleted when the instance terminates or specify 2 if volume remains after 

        instance terminates" 
        read vol_del
            if [$vol_del!=0 or $vol_del!=1] then
            echo "Specify either 1 or 0"
            fi

        echo "Specify display name for instance"
        read inst_disp_name

        echo "Creating instance"
        nova boot --flavor $flavor_id --block_device_mapping vda=$vol_id:$vol_type:$vol_size:$vol_del $inst_disp_name

}
```

Comment: Use `while true; do` on line 13.

Answer (score 1):

```
While true do
```

Bash is case-sensitive - you need `while` rather than `While`.  And you also need to either move the `do` to the next line or put a semicolon before it

```
while true; do
```

Also your `if` condition further down is suspect:

```
if [$vol_del!=0 or $vol_del!=1] then
```

Aside from the syntax errors, this condition will *always* be true (since if the value is 1 then it is not 0 and vice versa).  I suspect you wanted and rather than or:

```
if [ $vol_del != 0 -a $vol_del != 1 ]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
while true; do
```

instead of

```
While true do
```

because do isn't an argument to true command

Answer (score 1):

In theory, `do` should be on a separate line:

```
while ....
do
    ....
done
```

Same with `then`:

```
if .....
then
    .....
fi
```

However, people like putting them on the same line in the K&R Style. To do that, you need a semicolon to show the shell when the `while` line ends, so the `do` is on a *different line*:

```
while ....; do
    ....
done
```

This may no longer be necessary in newer versions of BASH, but it should be done. I prefer using an extra line just because the shell prefers it.

The other problem and the actual problem has to do with the `While` on line #13 as `While` (uppercase `W` and not lowercase `w`).

Two thing will help catch this in the future:

- Use `set -xv` to turn on *debugging* and `set +xv` to turn off debugging. In this case, you'll see the error happens when you enter the `while` loop when Line #13 gets executed. You can set `export PS4=\$LINENO+` to show line numbers when this debugging is on. To turn off debugging, you `set +xv`.
- Use a program editor that has syntax highlighting. I saw this immediately because the `While` wasn't in the *correct* color. I took a closer look and saw the capitalized `While`.

Comment: Thanks it worked :)....i more thing i am new to shell programming, could you please tell me which program editor should i use that has syntax highlighting?

Comment: @user3114615 If you are a true manly man type of Geek, you use [VIM](http://vim.org). VIM is powerful, but takes about six months to master. It's what I use. If you are a wimp -- or just rather get some actual work done instead of learning an arcane piece of software from the 1970s -- you can use almost any ***program*** editor you like. [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) is an IDE that works on various platforms. On the PC [Notepad++](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org) is popular. On the Mac, it's usually BBEdit or TextWrangler from [BareBones Software](http://www.barebones.com).